# Picklist issue with the flow for updating the text field

Tags: visual-workflow

I am trying to create a flow that will update the name field of a custom dsf_gym__c object to a combination of 3 fields named gym_type__c (picklist), number__c(auto number)  and member_type__c(picklist).
I am not able to write a formula for the same.
I am trying to do it only for gym_type__c first and it is printing the value as 01, 02,03,etc. these values are the corresponding values of the picklist value positioned in the list.
The value I used under Set Field Values for the dsf_gym Record is {!$Record.gym_type__c }

Attaching a screenshot of flow I made till now. Any guidance is appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try `TEXT({!$Record.gym_type__c }) + TEXT(number__c) + TEXT(member_type__c)` for your flow text formula to update the Name value.

You might want to make sure the dsf_gym__c object's Record Name is set to the Data Type of Text under Object Manager -> Details.